# Invoking cucumber from Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am trying to invoke cucumber from a Spring boot app. I have all the dependencies in my gradle build file. 
    compile("info.cukes:cucumber-java8:1.2.5")
    compile("info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.5")
    compile("info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.2.5")
And on examing my app's spring boot jar, I see the cucumber jars.

In the main class I have

```
        String[] cucumberOptions = new String[]{"--glue","mypackage.steps","--plugin", "pretty",
                "--plugin", "html:target/cucumber-html-report","--plugin", "json:target/cucumber.json",
                "--plugin", "junit:target_junit/cucumber.xml",
                "classpath:mypackage.features"
               };

 cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(cucumberOptions );
```

On executing my jar, I get the error -
No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.

I also have a runner class and corresponding step classes.
I have my step classes with the following annotation-

```
@ContextConfiguration(
        loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class,
        classes={Application.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MySteps{
....
}
My runner class is below.

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class MyRunner{

}
```

Question - is how do I invoke cucumber from my Spring boot app?

Answer (score 0):

i got this to work by updating my spring boot gradle script to use a fat jar boot repackage option.
Still curious as to why the spring boot integrated jar does not work though.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by instructing spring=boot-maven-plugin to unpack the cucumber-java jar

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <requiresUnpack>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </requiresUnpack>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```